# Should posts that show a high level of effort but with a low view count be "poked" more often?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, views

For example,

- User A writes a nicely detailed post (`>5000~` chars) tagged with a couple of popular tags.
- But, since there's so many new posts/hour for those tags his post quickly gets bumped to oblivion, *never to been seen again...*
- User A notices that his post has only had `<50~` views, maybe a *couple* of votes, nothing much.
- User A is then "put-off"/discouraged from making future good contributions, feeling that it was a complete waste of time due to a lack of attention that is genuinely deserved.

I'm sure some of us have experienced/witnessed this situation; so with that in mind, wouldn't it be a good idea to "poke" posts (that show a good level of effort; since anyone can write a few sentences) more often (until `X` views has been reached?) that have: `> X` chars, no downvotes, low views & no flags?

Comment: So someone's log dump shows a high level of effort then?

Comment: @Ben That's why I said "*...no downvotes, ... & no flags*".

Comment: Extremely wordy posts aren't all that great either. Trust me on this, I have rather a lot of experience with overly-long posts.

Comment: @Shog9 What if, say the user takes longer than `X` time to write the post (and if the post isn't like a few sentences long)?

Comment: >5000~ chars usually indicates a wall-of-code/text post to be honest. No wonder no one's reading it. The heuristic to determine "effort" is definitely not post length or anything to do with tags.

Comment: @WesleyMurch `>5000~` was just an example. I didn't intend for it to be taken literally.

Comment: @Sam How would the system determine "high level of effort"? I guess you mean "posts with upvotes"?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Time taken to write the post, post length, downvote count & flag count. Open to suggestions of course.

Comment: How long it takes to write the post *definitely* has nothing to do with it either. I often write my posts in notepad for one example. The only thing I can see mattering it votes.

Comment: When you say "User A is then "put-off"/discouraged from making future good contributions", you really mean asking more questions, right? Is this essentially the problem you're trying to tackle here?

Comment: @WesleyMurch No, not necessarily; user A could of posted a detailed answer to a dead question, for example.

Comment: Answers bump the post to front page though. I still don't get what the issue is: what problem are you addressing?

Comment: @WesleyMurch So the post gets bumped, it's on the front page for a few mins, then we're back to square one again. The point I'm trying to make is that sometimes when a user posts something detailed + useful (admittedly that is becoming a reality) the post can and does get overlooked, due to a number of reasons (mainly sheer posts/hour, for popular tags).

Comment: I never experienced that questions with a good research and a interesting topic doesn't got enough attention/up-votes. And even if this would happen you can still set a bounty, and again then, if the question is good, you will get the "wasted" rep back trough all the up-votes.

Answer (score 5):

No, I don't think this is a good idea.

**If we use post length:**

There are plenty of posts I just skip because they're too long.

Sometimes I downvote and/or vote to close, but not all that often (at least not purely based on post length, although code length is a different story) (not having read it at all / in much detail doesn't put me in a good position to judge the usefulness).

I already chose not to answer them, so I wouldn't really want them floating around the front page.

It's actually very rarely that I find a long question particularly useful - there may be some, but they are extremely difficult to get just right, and it's extremely rare that that much detail is actually required (as opposed to just having a lot of unnecessary details).

**If we use time taken to write:**

This seems like a fairly trivial constraint.

I suspect you intend for steps like this:

- Start writing a question.
- Do a ton of research.
- Finish writing the question.

But I imagine the steps are more along the lines of:

- Do any / most research you will do.
- Start writing a question.
- Perhaps do a teensy bit more research.
- Finish writing the question.

Thus, by the time you've started writing your question, you may already have done all / most research required to make this is really useful question.

The fact that you took a bathroom break or went to the mall in the middle of writing your question, that there are a lot of details required, or just that you write slow, doesn't seem particularly relevant to question quality.

**Is the quality of the question relevant to the amount of effort put into it?**

Even if we manage to judge the amount of effort put into a question accurately, is this a useful metric?

I don't really think so.

You could have a quick question and a brief Google search can tell you that finding an answer online isn't going to be easy, and it could turn out to be an immensely useful question.

On the other hand, you could spend hours writing a post and it could end up only being useful to you.

**Question quality - is that all that's important?**

Pretty much (well, answer quality as well).

While we don't really want to have users who could potentially ask good questions to get discouraged (because that's bad for question quality in the long term), if we favour the questions of users who might have potential, the *actual* good questions will disappear into the void instead.

**So what should we do?**

Reduce the low quality content so we could get a decent answer rate and more attention to give to users with potential.

- Let users jump through a few hoops before being allowed to ask a question
- Change the post-then-review model to a review-then-post one

I mentioned these before (somewhere...), so I won't go into more detail here.